# Can't see the syntax issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to save the amount of points each player(p) scored, in each game(g), to a dictionary keyed by their opponent.
I am getting a syntax issue in the following code:

```
opponents = {}
for p in range(len(league_data['elements'])):
    for g in range(len(game_data[str(league_data['elements'][p]['id'])]['history'])):
        #skip games where the player played 0 minutes
        if game_data[str(league_data['elements'][p]['id'])]['history'][g]['minutes'] == 0: continue
        opp = team_list[game_data[str(league_data['elements'][p]['id'])]['history'][g]['opponent_team']
        points = game_data[str(league_data['elements'][p]['id'])]['history'][g]['total_points']
        opponents.setdefault(opp, [0,0])[0] += points
        opponents[opp][1] += 1
```

I'm getting the error on the following line:

```
points = game_data[str(league_data['elements'][p]['id'])]['history'][g]['total_points']
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I can't see the problem. Also if I write the line out in a seperate cell and print `points` it works fine.

Comment: Could you please add a plain python tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It complains about this line because the line above isn't fully contained. The line above implicitly continues the `[` to the next line where it encounters an assignment (which is invalid here).

Comment: Thanks, been coding all day, just could't see the missing `]`